# Cross-module inlining of internal modules

Tags: haskell, optimization, inline, ghc, cabal

I have a cabal package with a lot of internal modules (the `other-modules` field). I believe that I'll benefit from inlining most of the functions in them.

Do I have to go thru them all inserting pragmas or GHC and Cabal are smart enough to do the inlining on their own? If they are, then how will this inlining be performed? If otherwise I have to walk thru inserting a pragma, which one should I prefer: `INLINE` or `INLINABLE` (or maybe even the synthetic [`inline` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v%3ainline)) - and for what reason?

Comment: Have you measured which functions benefit from inlining?

Comment: No. I just concluded so from the design point of view. The package is basically implemented as a multi-level composition, i.e., a lot of functions are merely a composition of simpler functions from other modules, which are internal. A lot of people would have implemented such functions without decomposition, so I thought that compiler could do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC will do a pretty good job at high levels of optimization.

If, after inspecting the Core and profiling, you determine that certain functions are not inlined when they could be, you can use INLINABLE or INLINE to increase the liklihood of inlining occuring.

[Recall](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/pragmas.html) that

> The major effect of an INLINE pragma is to declare a function's “cost” to be very low. The normal unfolding machinery will then be very keen to inline it.
>
> While INLINE says "please inline me", the INLINABLE says "feel free to inline me; use your discretion"

INLINABLE is usually the better choice, as you don't know what all call sites will look like.

However, it only makes sense to do this if you profile and are unhappy with performance, and can demonstrate that the performance is improved via inlining.

Comment: Thank you. So basically, Cabal does not present the `other-modules` to GHC any differently than the `exposed-modules`? I just expected them to be optimized (and hence inlined) more aggressively, since it won't affect the package API.

Comment: No, Cabal has no specific effect on how modules in a package are optimized.